# Azure runbook for rebooting VMs via multiple tags query

Tags: azure, tags, reboot, runbook

I am aware of how to reboot/schedule reboots for a VM that has one tag. However, I'm having difficulty finding out how to reboot a VM based on the presence of multiple tags. Is this possible?

For example: 
If VM has Tag 1= True and Tag 2=True, then I want it to reboot. 
If either tag is false, don't reboot. 
If either tag is missing, don't reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to use Azure runbook to restart your VMs with some tags?

If I am right, maybe you can use this script to do it:

```
$connectionname = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-Automationconnection -Name $connectionname
    Login-AzureRmAccount -servicePrincipal -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -applicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.applicationId -certificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.certificatethumbprint   
}
catch{
    if (!$serviceprincipalconnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$VMs = Get-AzureRMVm | Where {$_.Tags.keys -contains "Tier" -and $_.Tags.Values -eq "2" -and $_.Tags.Values -eq "1"} | select Name, ResourceGroupName, Tags
ForEach ($vm in $vms)
{
    $VMStatus2 = Get-AzureRMVM -Name $VM.Name -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Status

    $VMName = $VM.Name
    $VMRG = $VM.ResourceGroupName
    $VMPS = $VMStatus2.Statuses[1].DisplayStatus
        If ($VMPS-eq "VM Running")
            {
                Restart-AzureRMVM -Name $VMName -ResourceGroupName $VMRG -force
                "$VMName is restarting"
            }
}
```

You can use that script to list VMs with tag key contain `Tier` and Value are `1` and `2`.

Here is my screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help. Also if it helps, please don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks:)